# Analyze the probability of a porfolio increasing (or decreasing) by certain amounts

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, portfolio

I would like to build a portfolio (of funds) which I don't need to manage often.

In principle I am relatively happy to allocate the money in higher risk funds, since I don't plan on using it in the near future. However, it is unclear exactly what the risk levels really mean.

Is there some way to analyze a portfolio which gives a meaningful likelyhood of the expected portfolio's worth over time?

Either by calculating based on some quantities given in the fund datasheets or via a tool.

As an example I would like to calculate the following scenario with input:

- I start with $10,000 invested in one high risk and one medium risk fund with equal distribution

And it would tell me:

- In 5 years time there is a 90% probability the portfolio will be worth more than $10,000
- In 5 years time there is a 60% probability the portfolio will be worth more than $15,000
- In 5 years time there is a 20% probability the portfolio will be worth more than $25,000
- In 5 years time there is a 5% probability the portfolio will be worth more than $50,000

Comment: Just a word of caution - it sounds like you are asking for detailed calculations which would require a high level of sophistication to interpret, but it's not clear that you personally have that level of sophistication. Be very careful about being overly confident in investing in risky assets which you may not understand.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I have a background in mathematics but not in finance. So I have sufficient understanding to make the calculations and interpret probabilities given in the answer below, but I don't have sufficient understanding to analyze them in a financial context... do you have any specific advice regarding how exactly to be cautious? Alternatively, suggested reading so I can be confident I am making a good choice with my investments, based on the calculations of probability given by the answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are ways. Simulation like this are divided into 2 methods:

- Historical Method: Select random periods of 5 years of actual historical returns from a fixed portfolio.
- Statistical Method: Also known as Monte Carlo simulation. Define Mean and Standard Deviation. Assume Log Normal distribution for portfolio returns (not portfolio price).

Second method is more applicable because most "Funds" only have 10-30 year history. Let's simplify by assuming just 1 asset (e.g. S&P 500) that has a very long history.
It has an annual mean log return of around 10% and annualized standard deviation of log return of around 15%.

An example of Log Return if price increased from $1.0 to $1.1 is:

- =LN(1.1/1.0)
- =0.0953101798043249
- where [e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))^0.0953101798043249=1.1/1.0 (Non Log Return was 10% Increase)

An example of Log Return if price decreased from $1.1 to $1.0 is:

- =LN(1.0/1.1)
- =-0.0953101798043249
- where [e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))^-0.0953101798043249=1.0/1.1 (Non Log Return was 9.1% Decrease)

The Log Return using Excel after 1 year in a random scenario is:

- =NORMINV(RAND(),0.10,0.15)

The portfolio value of an investment of $1 after 1 year in this random scenario is:

- =EXP(NORMINV(RAND(),0.10,0.15))

The portfolio value of an investment of $1 after 5 years in this random scenario is:

- =EXP(NORMINV(RAND(),0.10,0.15))*EXP(NORMINV(RAND(),0.10,0.15))*EXP(NORMINV(RAND(),0.10,0.15))*EXP(NORMINV(RAND(),0.10,0.15))*EXP(NORMINV(RAND(),0.10,0.15))

To measure the probability of exceeding $1.0, $1.5, $2.5, $5.0 in 5 years, just paste the longest formula 100 times in 100 different Excel cells. Then count how many of the 100 cells exceeded 1.0, 1.5, 2.5, 5.0.

For example, to calculate which of 100 scenario exceeded $1.5:

- =COUNTIF([Range of 100 cells],">1.5")/COUNTA([Range of 100 cells])

Once you know how to do above, just test all possible allocations of the 2 assets, then understand the probability. In fact, there should only be one combination of the 2 asset that results in Best Sharpe Ratio (Mean divided by SD). You should simply use that, then scale the Mean and SD using Leverage. If the asset is simply S&P 500 then the implicit financing of Futures is closer to 0.4% per year impact on the mean for each 1x additional leverage.

Note that Monte Carlo simulation does not accurately reflect Black Swan events like 2008-2009, 1929 etc.

Here is a rough Excel that I made:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/2bfnmj251uawktn/Monte_Carlo_100_Scenarios.xlsx/file

Normally, it is better to try 10,000 scenarios rather than just 100 scenarios.

[image]

If you want to skip the Excel, you can try third party online tools like https://www.portfoliovisualizer.com/monte-carlo-simulation Choose "Simulation Model: Historical Returns" then type your 2 asset tickers or "Simulation Model: Parametrized Return" then type Mean and SD. However, that tool does not support leverage.

Comment: Is there a way to artificially simulate black swan events, e.g. lets say something like this happens once every 50 years, it could be incorporated by a value crash of 50% with a probability of 0.02?

Comment: No, according to the person who popularized black swan: https://www.investopedia.com/articles/trading/11/black-swan-events-investing.asp "Taleb argues that the standard tools of probability and prediction, such as the normal distribution, do not apply"

Comment: I would like to calculate the mean log return and mean standard deviation for swedish funds but there isnt data immediately available. Is there a way to calculate this using "standard deviation" from e.g. morning star (i guesss this is just non-log standard deviation?), or do i need to download the fund data and calculate it myself?

Comment: E.g. for S&P500 the standard deviation is given here as 13.19 over 10 years and the mean return is 14.8 https://www.morningstar.com/indexes/spi/spx/risk

Comment: Sometimes a data provider actually meant log return. Most of the time they meant arithmatic return. Without the underlying data (e.g. day, week, month), there is no way to convert average arithmatic return to average log return. You can approximate by trying Mean_Log = LN(1 + Mean_Arith). For SD, I think you can take the SD_Arith as is.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. Morningstar shows "Geometric Annual Return from 10-Year Total Return". Meaning that (1+Mean_Morningstar)^10 =(e^LN(1+Mean_Morningstar))^10. So you can directly convert Morningstar Mean using Mean_Log = LN(1 + Mean_Geo) and it is accurate.

Comment: and the standard deviation is equal to the log standard deviation?

Comment: I roughly tested in Excel and it seems that SD_Log = LN(1 + SD_Geo) makes the whole thing less accurate. I would just try SD_Log = SD_Geo. Try other answers https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241187/calculating-standard-deviation-after-log-transformation

Comment: okay thank you! on the other hand, if i download the data and try different scenarios, first to calculate the best sharpe ratio, then to calculate the monte carlo simulations, should i calculate the mean log returns and SD for each asset seperately, or should i calculate them for each % allocation?

Comment: You should ways calculate as a Portfolio for each % allocation because 2 assets are not Independent. There is usually Negative Correlation / Covariance between Stock and Bonds (including between High Risk and Low Risk). A word of note, relying on negative correlation to maximize return minimize SD also has its limitations, namely on the Statistical Significance of the Correlation / Covariance.

Comment: in your original answer you say to scale the mean and standard deviation using leverage, how do you mean?

Comment: If you had $100 and borrowed another $100 to buy $200 funds in total, the mean and standard deviation in relation to the original $100 is times 2. Suppose that a fund makes $4 on $100 in a year. By buying $200, you get $208 before paying back the loan of $100. After paying back the Loan, you have $108 left, meaning that you made $8.

Comment: maybe it requires a separate question, but while this sounds like a good idea in principle, are there (1) specific types of loans which i should use for this, i guess low interest? (2) ways to mitigate against the risk of going bankrupt, even if the chance of not having enough money at the end of the year is only 1%, that still feels like a relatively large risk for something so serious, especially given this is based on a model ignoring black swan events?

Comment: (2) is a separate question on risk management. (1) for S&P 500 Futures and EURO STOXX 50 Futures etc are based on annualized 3 month central bank interest rate, and for other stocks/funds refer to your broker's website e.g. https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/trading/margin-rates.php . If the leverage is less than 1.0 (e.g. buy 70% High Risk Fund + 30% Cash), you can use central bank interest rate or bank deposit rates.